# Using Long script returned 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: php, error-handling

I am running a PHP script that takes around 1 hour to complete its execution. But I get this error after some time:

```
 502 Bad Gateway

 The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
```

And in this script I used `sleep(rand(10,20))` for several times. Is that sleep function reason for this error because of too much delay? What can I do to fix this issue?

Details about the script:
This is a scrapping script which crawl a remote website to extract its data and insert into database.
I used Proxy through cURL.
And I intentionally added that huge sleep interval to reflect as normal user not spam or robot. So that is why this script takes that long time to complete process.
Is this error because of no resonse from remote website?

Comment: Check your error log for the actual error and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too unclear to be answered, like what you are trying to do with your script... atleast add that much.

Though I don't think sleep must be giving a bad gateway error.
Bad gateway is the error you get while accessing a server through some other server or browser and you recieved an invalid response.
This is mostly because of error on server side (not client)

It can be made clearer if you could attach your code and tell your aim with it.
Also, I think that taking an hour for a service is too much time anyway.

Comment: And as PeeHaa said, you should check your error log too.

Comment: Hi @vish4071 I just added description about the script. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, I believe so... A while ago...I also wrote a code for seb-scraper (a basic one, motive was to learn regex and building a scraper) as bash script. I don't think you need the sleep anyway. But that bad gateway is not the error of your script.

Comment: though, if you want, I can share the bash script with you (which might help a bit, if not much)